# How to get a value from a table that a value is referenced from?

Tags: postgresql

I've two Postgres tables.

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    id serial primary key,
    question varchar(64) unique
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE answers (
    id serial primary key,
    answerer serial references users(id), -- todo left off here, did not have answerer column
    question serial references questions(id),
    answer int
);
```

I want to write a query that returns the answers table id (answers.id) and question text (questions.id) where the answer is 1 in one query.

I've tried a query:

```
SELECT (id, question) FROM answers WHERE answer=1 UNION SELECT question FROM questions WHERE id=(SELECT (id) FROM answers WHERE answer=1 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 15;
```

and it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "join".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.question,
        a.answer
FROM    Answers a
INNER JOIN Questions q 
    ON q.id = a.question
WHERE a.answer = 1
```

The `JOIN` syntax is described in the PostgreSQL documentation "[2.6. Joins Between Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html)"

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> A query that accesses multiple rows of the same or different tables at one time is called a **join query**.

Comment: Although this answer might be correct, it is lacking an explanation. Including reference material (PostgreSQL JOIN) and a short explanation would greatly enhance the value of this answer. Oh, and your answer contained a typo which I fixed during the re-formatting.